# Simple ubuntu pod in microk8s fail to ping external servers

Tags: networking, microk8s

Simple ubuntu pod in microk8s fail to ping external servers. Following is the deployment manifest.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: myapp 
  name: valet-pod 
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: valet-pod 
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: valet-pod 
        tenantid: softwareag
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: valet-pod 
          image: ubuntu 
          command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
          args:
            - apt-get update -y;
              apt-get install -y curl traceroute net-tools iputils-ping;
              echo "Sleeping for 5000";
              sleep 5000;
```

However, docker container passes to ping any external server.

This is happening in a ubuntu 18 in a laptop.  Following are the network settings.

```
ufw allow in on cbr0
ufw default allow FORWARD
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

What tool can be used to troubleshoot such scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the microk8s 1.16 version, the network interface is ***cni0*** which used to be ***cbr0*** in the lower versions of microk8s.

So, the fix was to allow incoming packets on interface cni0 (instead of cbr0).

`ufw allow in on cni0`

This solved the issue.